# Draw Image: Center, Horizontal, Bottom in Java

Tags: android, xml, imageview, alignment

This is my first attempt at drawing an image outside of xml in all java.  How can I:

1. Create a new imageView
2. Attach a drawable to the imageView
3. Display the imageView to the screen
4. Align the imageView to the bottom of the screen and centered vertically

All in java code?

Also, how can I "destroy" the image when I am done displaying it?

Answer (score 0):

this "4. Align the imageView to the **bottom of the screen** and **centered vertically**" is not possible, just think about it !

so in **following code** i am **showing imageView centered Horizontal**

```
    LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
    l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    l.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    l.addView(iv);
    setContentView(l);// or add to any view to whom you want to display it !
```

---

```
Also, how can I "destroy" the image when I am done displaying it
```

**it depends on the code how you displays it**

Comment: I already have a relative layout I am adding this imageView to.  How would I add it to the current layout?